# ¿se puede enmascarar el nombre de dominio con .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

estoy trabajando en un proyecto y quería saber si puedo enmascarar el nombre del domino por otro (que aun no esta contratado -no existe-).
Ejemplo:

Dominio online de la web: example.com

Domino a mostrar: example2.com (sin que éste exisista)

¿Se puede esto?

Comment: parece ser mas una redireccion que del dominio 1 te lleve al 2 ?

Comment: Si, pero el dominio 2 no existe (es solo para enmascarar el nombre del dominio 1) entonces el usuario solo puede ver: ejemplo: domino2.com (cuando en realidad esta en dominio1.com. Se entiende?

Comment: aaa ok pues hasta donde yo se eso no se puede hacer los 2 dominios deberian estar creados y por medio de una redireccion hay si que te lleve al dominio que quieres

Comment: :( Gracias por tu atención Oscar.

Comment: Supongamos que podés enmascararlo... Cuando un navegador intente acceder a `example2.com`, el navegador va a realizar la petición al IP de ese dominio, y nunca pasaría por tu servidor. No hay nada que puedas hacer para atrapar una petición a un dominio que no es tuyo.

Comment: Mi sugerencia es que jamás dependas de un dominio para ningún desarrollo.

Answer (score 0):

No se puede enmascarar, pero sí puedes redireccionar a otro dominio poniendo esta línea en tu htaccess:

```
Redirect /index.php http://otrodominio.com
```

O bien, puedes utilizar este otro código

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tusitio.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ otrositio.com [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Si, eso lo sé, solo que no sabía si se puede enmascarar el dominio hasta que se contrate un servicio para destino online.

Comment: `^tusitio.com` debería ser `^tusitio\.com$`... Y, además, al redireccionar a otro dominio, se esperaría que mantenga la misma ruta.